# Connecting to SSL-enabled Oracle DB through Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jdbc

I'm doing a Proof-of-Concept (PoC) Java reporting project in which I'm connecting to a SSL-enabled Oracle database from my workstation, using JDBC Thin driver. As the database is SSL-enabled, I added all the required certificates into a Oracle Wallet and provided its location in the Java code. The certs were also added *cacert* of the JRE. Java code excerpt -

```
    try {
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("ERROR: Oracle JDBC Driver not found");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;
    String oracleURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=2484)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service>)))";

    // Provide user ID, password for schema     
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "<user id>");
    props.setProperty("password", "<password>");

    // Setting properties for SSL
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites", "(ssl_rsa_export_with_rc4_40_md5, ssl_rsa_export_with_des40_cbc_sha, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_client_authentication", "false");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_version", "3.0");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REJECTED");
    props.setProperty("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client", "REJECTED");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\APP\\ORACLE\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\ewallet.p12");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","PKCS12");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","Password1");

    try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL, props); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
      System.out.println("Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());
      System.out.println("SQL State: " + e.getSQLState());
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
```

I'm able to compile the program and also run it using the following -

```
java -cp z:\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\ojdbc14.jar;z:\jdk1.7.0_13\bin OracleConnCheck
```

where:

- z:\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\ojdbc14.jar - location of ojdbc14.jar
- z:\jdk1.7.0_13\bin - Java classpath
- OracleConnCheck - Java class

But I always encounter IO error accompanied with NL exception or SO exception. I checked out the Oracle and few articles related to the same exception in here but none addressed my exact problem. Could someone help? Thanks!

Edit: Adding the stacktrace -

```
    Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
Error code: 17002
SQL State: null
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: NL Exception was generated
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
        at OracleConnCheck.establishConnection(OracleConnCheck.java:51)
        at OracleConnCheck.main(OracleConnCheck.java:72)

------- The End -------
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158509/oracle-jdbc-thin-driver-ssl?rq=1

Comment: @RC - Thanks for the pointer. The referenced post displays a similar problem and the suggestions provided there were tested, to no avail. Hence posted my problem.

Comment: Maybe https://community.oracle.com/thread/634132?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the latest 12.1.0.2 JDBC drivers.  You can download from [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html). Also, you need to include osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar.

Refer to [SSL with Oracle JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) whitepaper for more details.

Comment: I used **ojdbc7.jar** and the other JARs as well but it still throws the error. I had referred the Oracle document as well before posting it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"NL Exception was generated" indicates that there is a format error in the connection string. In your case you are missing `=` after `DESCRIPTION`.