# tcps oracle tomcat thin driver not working

Tags: oracle, tomcat, driver, thin

I need help with a new environment that I am setting up

Tomcat (wallet + jdbc thin driver) --> TCPS --> Oracle 12

I have been following this post ([Oracle JDBC thin driver SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158509/oracle-jdbc-thin-driver-ssl)) with no luck

When I try to start-up Tomcat, the following error is shown

```
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not   correct: got 256 but was expecting 128
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1219)
```

I think I'm missing something but I don't know where..

Oracle side

listener.ora

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /u01/app/oracle/wallet)
    )
  )

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 72795752816f)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = 72795752816f)(PORT = 2484))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

sqlnet.ora

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = /u01/app/oracle/wallet)
     )
   )

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS,BEQ)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,     SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5)

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

Tomcat Side

tnsnames.ora

```
TEST =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCPS)
    (HOST = 72795752816f)
    (PORT = 2484)
  )
   (CONNECT_DATA = 
    (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
    (SERVICE_NAME = xe.oracle.docker)   
   )
 )
```

context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/edorasone" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:/@TEST"
  connectionProperties="javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/tomcat/wallet/cwallet.sso;\
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PCKS12;\
oracle.net.ssl_version=1.0;\
oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=(SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5);\
oracle.net.authentication_services=( TCPS )"
/>
```

BTW: If a use a sqlplus client in Tomcat with the sqlnet.ora(=Oracle) & tnsnames.ora (=Tomcat) I can connect with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Do you have additional jars required for using Oracle wallets ? (oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, osdt_cert.jar) ?
(2) Correct the javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12.  You have a typo there.
(3) DB URL should be "jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST" and since you are using an alias, you need to set a system property -Doracle.net.tns_admin=(a) Do you have additional jars required for using Oracle wallets ? (oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, osdt_cert.jar) ?

Check out the [SSL with JDBC whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help.
a) yes, they were in place
b) It works with PCKS12
c) tns_admin was into the setenv.sh script

Finally I got my set-up working now.

SSL_CIPHER_SUITES must match in both sides, so what I did was to force the same cipher

sqlnet.ora

```
 SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
```

setenv.sh

```
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Doracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA "
```

(Note to the prefix is not the same: SSL_ in Oracle side, and TLS_ in Tomcat/Java side)

For those ones with problems with similar configurations,, I let the Tomcat config side here

```
###############################
# DB CONNECTION CONFIGURATION #
###############################
# Oracle DB (JNDI)
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Dspring.profiles.active=database-jndi "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/tomcat/wallet "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/tomcat/wallet/keystore.jks "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=Passw0rd  "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tomcat/wallet/truststore.jks  "    
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=Passw0rd  "                 
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Doracle.net.authentication_services=TCPS   "
CATALINA_OPTS+=" -Doracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA "
```

context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/efdesone" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:/@TEST"
  username="<username>" password="<password>" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
/>
```

Kind regards

Nacho.